# How to select a number received from the serial port

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I receive data from a motion sensor device through a serial port.
The data is formatted in lines and start by a letter, like this:

[image]

All numbers are separated by commas and there is '\r' character at the end of each line.

I am interested getting numbers from the lines which start with 'S' character which always has 11 number between commas. For example, I would like to save in a variable (an array or a list) the second number of that 'S' lines.

I have been trying this simple Python script:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial-00002014', 115200)
try:
    ser.isOpen()
    #ser.flushInput()
    print('serial is open')
except:
    print('error')
    exit()

if (ser.isOpen()):
    try:
        while(1):
            print(ser.read())
    except Exception:
        print('error')
else:
    print('Cannot open serial port')
```

The result is continuously printing characters the port receives

```
b'S'
b','
b'0'
b','
b'0'
b','
b'0'
b','
b'-'
b'2'
b'8'
b','
b'2'
b'1'
b','
b'9'
b'8'
b'5'
b','
b'-'
b'1'
b'5'
b'3'
b','
b'3'
b'0'
b'5'
b','
b'-'
b'1'
b'0'
b'7'
b','
b'1'
b'2'
b'1'
b','
b'9'
b'0'
b'\r'
b'Q'
```

and it seems difficult to get the numbers I need.

Is there any way to get the second number of the 'S' lines?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to read the docs?
You can use a [readline](http://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/shortintro.html#readline) to read a complete line and then split it into words. Something like this:

```
numbers = []
with serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial-00002014', 19200, timeout=10) as ser:
    line = ser.readline()
    if line.startswith('S,'):
        number = int(line.split(',')[1])
        numbers.append(number)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have tried `readline()` changing the EOL with `import io   ser_io = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(ser, ser, 1), newline = '\r', line_buffering = True)` and now the script gets the entire line and with your code I am able to get the first number. However, `numbers` has too many numbers inside after a few seconds. Do you know how to keep the last 200 numbers received?. I would like to make a plot of them and to compute the fft.

Comment: @pablo probably it is worth to look at [deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-recipes)